# HTML/CSS Overflow issue

Tags: html, css

Given this layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/7xVAu/

The second(yellow) example is the layout im aiming for, as im happy for the grey element to completely overflow it's container, however setting `width:99999px;` is a 'hacky' approach.

Setting `position:absolute` on the grey box will also get the desired effect, however it will remove its spacing for the next element, and I cannot set a `height` property for this element.

Is there a neater solution?

Edit: for clarification: I want it to behave exactly like the `width:99999px` version, but without setting `width:99999px` as i feel that is a hacky approach.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Should the grey box only have a single line of text, or should it wrap to multiple lines? Should it always stretch across the page, or should it only be as wide as necessary?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, have clarified in question :)

Comment: So the grey div should grow to be as wide as necessary to fit the text inside of it and show it all on one line?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the div should grow as wide as necessary for it's containing item(s), be it a string of text or a div

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question exactly. But if you were looking for a different way to do the same thing, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/7xVAu/15/.

Use %'s as in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xVAu/15/) and use `position:relative;`. As you can see, it gives the same effect, but the % depends on the size of the container, which is a bigger benefit. If you adjust the width of the yellow container, the grey one will adjust also, whilst still overflowing the yellow box :) ALSO it allows you to adjust the height with no problems at all!

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/7xVAu/33/) in which the text is floated?

```
style="background:#777; margin:0 9px 9px 9px; float:left; white-space:nowrap; height:40px;"
```

I am not sure if I understood the question though.